# Is Parvati also known as Narayani?

Tags: vishnu, name, parvati

Parvati is the sister of Vishnu. One of the other names of Vishnu is Narayan.
Is Parvati also known as Narayani ?

Comment: You know about this mantra? -- https://greenmesg.org/stotras/durga/sarvamangala_mangalye.php

Comment: Narayana sahodari (sister) iti Narayani.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Parvati is indeed Called Narayani.

Scriptures also mentions why she is called so.

> **Brahma Vaivarta Purana , Prakriti Khanda Chapter 57.**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Lord Vishnu prays to Maa Yoga Māyā to born as his sister as the daughter of Mata Yashoda and save Lord BalaRāma and him from Kamsa.

**S.B. 10.2.9-12.:**

> *अथाहमंशभागेन देवक्या: पुत्रतां शुभे । प्राप्स्यामि त्वं यशोदायां नन्दपत्न्‍यां भविष्यसि ॥ ९ ॥
> अर्चिष्यन्ति मनुष्यास्त्वां सर्वकामवरेश्वरीम् । धूपोपहारबलिभि: सर्वकामवरप्रदाम् ॥ १० ॥
> नामधेयानि कुर्वन्ति स्थानानि च नरा भुवि । दुर्गेति भद्रकालीति विजया वैष्णवीति च ॥ ११ ॥
> कुमुदा चण्डिका कृष्णा माधवी कन्यकेति च । माया **नारायणी**शानी शारदेत्यम्बिकेति च ॥ १२ ॥*
>
> *Oh all-auspicious One, then I shall also appear with my part expansion as the son of Devakī, and you will appear as the daughter of Yaśodā, the wife of Nanda. Everyone there will worship you with incences, lamps, presentations, sacrifices, etc as you are the All Supreme Goddess, who fulfills every ones' desires by giving them boons. Depending on different places on Earth, they will call you with different names, such as Durgā, Bhadrakālī, Vijayā, Vaiṣṇavī, Kumudā, Caṇḍikā, Kṛṣṇā, Mādhavī, Kanyakā, Māyā, **Nārāyaṇī,** Īśānī, Śāradā, Ambikā, etc.*

**Srimad Devi Bhagwatam Mahā Puranam 5.:1.:**

> *12-54. **Vyāsa said :**---"...She the Yoga Māyā who is indirectly, with the twinklings of Her eyes, creating, preserving and destroying this universe. It is the Yoga Māyā that caused Kṛṣṇa to be transferred from his lying-in chamber to the village Vraja and then protected him in the house of the cowherd Nanda; afterwards took him to Mathurā for the destruction of Kaṃsa,..."*

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..